# Yii2 mailer compose() used in a loop not resetting attachments

Tags: php, yii2, phpmailer

I have the following code, it will loop through $byCreatedBy array and
create xls files for each $createdBy and attach the one xls file for each
$createdBy.
But it seems

```
 $mail = \Yii::$app->mail->compose();
```

does not reinitialize the $attachment array resulting in the next messages having the attachment/s of the previous messages.

```
        foreach($byCreatedBy as $createdBy=>$data){
        $filename = \Yii::$app->params['data_dir']."pending-requisitions/pendingIR-".$createdBy.".xls";
        $this->xls = new MilPHPExcel;
        $this->writeRequisitions($data);
        $this->xls->outputFile($filename);
        $emailAddress = PeopleData::getEmailAddressByUsername($createdBy);

        $mail = \Yii::$app->mail->compose();
        $mail->setTo([
            'milwell@dexterton.loc' => 'Milwell',
        ])
        ->setSubject('Pending Internal Requistions')
        ->setHtmlBody(Yii::$app->view->render('/mail/pending-requisitions',[
            'username'=>$createdBy,
            'email'=>$emailAddress,
        ]))
        ->attach($filename)
        ->send();
        if($i>1)
            exit();
        $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

changed the mail code to:

```
        $mail = \Yii::$app->mail;
        $mail->adapter->clearAttachments();
        $message = $mail->compose();
        $message->setTo([
            'milwell@dexterton.loc' => 'Milwell',
        ])
        ->setSubject('Pending Internal Requistions')
        ->setHtmlBody(Yii::$app->view->render('/mail/pending-requisitions',[
            'username'=>$createdBy,
            'email'=>$emailAddress,
        ]));
        $message->attach($filename);
        $message->send();
```

The line:

```
        $mail->adapter->clearAttachments();
```

will clear attachments, since I'm using zyxphpmailer plugin